# IsDate Check allowing different local date formats

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting, regional-settings

I have a problem with VBA Code for an Excel macro in a file that is used both by users using the local date format dd.mm.yyyy as well as other users using the local format dd/mm/yyyy. This file contains a sheet where we need to import/copy paste data and then modify it via VBA code. The following part causes issues

```
While IsDate(Sheets(sSheet).Range("C" & i).Value) = True
    Sheets(sSheet).Range("A" & i).Value = Variable1
    Sheets(sSheet).Range("B" & i).Value = Variable2
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

The data we need to import has the dates in the format dd.mm.yyyy so the IsDate function returns false when users with the local format dd/mm/yyyy try to run this code. This causes problems.

Is there any elegant way to fix this so that IsDate returns the value True when users with the local format dd/mm/yyyy try to run the code? Can you somehow force a certain region/date setting for that check in VBA?

Many thanks!

Comment: The format has nothing to do with `IsDate` function return... Most probably, what you think is `Date` is, in fact, Text/string... Please, use a formula like `=Day("A2")`, supposing that in "A2" such a (pseudo) `Date` exists. Does it return the correct day, or `#VALUE` error?

Comment: Are you coping the data from some external source? If not, Excel date is actual a "serial number" (integer) - same in all locales.

Comment: Did you find some time to test what I suggested above? If not yet, please also verify if the date having the month number <=12 weren't already been converted as `Date`, but swapping the day with the month...? If so, I can post a function able to correct the problem.

Comment: @FaneDuru That's it, thanks a lot. Indeed for the US colleagues the =Day forumla returns a `#Value error`. Solution now was to have them replace the dots with slashes in the pseudo date column, then everything works as planned again. Not sure if there is also a fancy way in VBA to fix this but the find&replace option works too

Answer (score 1):

You could *replace* those dots:

```vb
While IsDate(Replace(Sheets(sSheet).Range("C" & i).Value, ".", "/") = True
    Sheets(sSheet).Range("A" & i).Value = Variable1
    Sheets(sSheet).Range("B" & i).Value = Variable2
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: This idea looks promising, however the code above does not work.
I get a compiling error message "Function call on left side of assignment must return Variant or Object". I also had to add some closing breakets on the left otherwise it's a syntax error. Any idea whats that error message about?

Comment: Sorry, Replace only has a purpose when validating the cell content. See edit answer, please.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that! `IsDate(Replace(Sheets(sSheet).Range("C" & i).Value, ".", "/";)` causes a syntax error if I change it to `IsDate(Replace(Sheets(sSheet).Range("C" & i).Value, ".", "/"))` I still get that weird "Function call on left side of assignment must return Variant or Object" compile error. However manuelly replacing dots with slashes with the Excel find&replace option before running the macro did actually work. Not sure if you can automate that via VBA somehow, that would be cool

Comment: I removed the semikolon.